# Passing boolean values during helm install

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, fusionauth

I am trying to deploy fusionauth using helm install and by setting environmental variables with value as boolean true or false, I am able to deploy but fusionauth is complaining it is not able to understand value "true", How to set this value as  `FUSIONAUTH_APP_SILENT_MODE: true` instead of `FUSIONAUTH_APP_SILENT_MODE: "true"`

```
helm upgrade --install \
fusionauth fusionauth \
--create-namespace \
--namespace fusionauth \
--set environment[0].name=FUSIONAUTH_APP_SILENT_MODE \
--set "environment[0].value="\true"\" \
--repo https://fusionauth.github.io/charts
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example?  Is the error coming from Kubernetes or the application?  An environment variable's value is always a string, but since `true` usually gets parsed in YAML as a boolean value, there can be some issues making sure it stays as a string from end to end in the pipeline.

Comment: when it gets deployed,, env variable's shows as FUSIONAUTH_APP_SILENT_MODE: "true" but when application starts, it throws error stating value can be either true or false without double quotes

Comment: Does removing the extra quotes from the `--set` option help?  You may need to force it to a string; `--set-string 'environment[0].value=true'`.